# Getting Not defining \perthousnad and Not defining \micro when compiling beamer with Kile

Tags: beamer, kile

I have some experience using LaTeX with Miktex on windows, but am only taking baby steps in learning how to do it on Ubuntu. I am using Kile as IDE for making beamer presentations. The pdf file is nicely generated after the compilation, however, I get the following error message:

```
./file.tex:0: Not defining \perthousnad 
./file.tex:0: Not defining \micro
```

I don't know what is going with Kile during compilation of beamer document classe! Could anyone suggest me any thing that may help!! thank you.

Comment: Hi! It seems like that Kile is "too clever". While I don't like such dirty tricks, you may see if adding `\let\micro\micro` and `\let\perthousand\perthousand` into the document preamble cheats Kile into thinking that they are defined. Btw, I suppose that `snad` in `\perthousnad` is a typo...

Comment: @tohecz Thank you! but putting these two line in the preamble did not change anything?

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik, no it doesn't change anything. `\let\bar\foo` just makes `\bar` a clone of the macrodefinition of `\foo`. In this case both are the same, so it's about the same as going to IKEA, take the chair you bought yesterday and change it with the exact same model, which is made with the same definition/design. It's not the same chair, but it does exactly the same as the original, and it has the same name ;).

Comment: @hugovdberg so what do you suggest as a solution of this mysterious problem?

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik Hmm, I'm sorry, I misread your question. I don't use Kile, so I'm afraid I can't help you on this one.

Comment: @hugovdberg okay no problem. If you find something interesting tell us about it after!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

They are not errors, but warnings from the `gensymb` package, and if you look in the `.log` file I think you'll find:

```
Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.

Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.
```

So it has nothing to with either `beamer` or Kile. If you don't use those two symbols, don't worry about it. If you want to get rid of those warnings anyway, you can load the `textcomp` package before `gensymb` with `\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}`. (Reference: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3364#p13124)

Comment: @{Torbjørn T.} how did you guess about `gensymb`, in the absence of a min.ex?

Comment: @wasteofspace I searched around a bit for the words in the warnings, and eventually found something about `gensymb`, can't remember exactly what. Looked in the documented source, and found those exact words. Then I searched some more, and found that thread from LaTeX Community.

Answer (score 11):

This error is generated by the `textcomp` packaged imported by `gensymb`. You can prevent it by explicitly importing `textcomp` before `gensymb`:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}

...
```

Comment: the shorter version can probably be: `\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}`